# only first row of table, record is updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi everyone. I am Using rails 3.2.13 with ruby 1.9.3.

I implementing jquery modal view. There is table with records. Some column have link called **Make Session End**. If i click on Make Session End link, a popup displays with two radio button end and break with button OK.

If i click ok it is working fine for **first record** of the table. But for other records OK button is not clicked so that **put** action is not permormed. Code is something like this:

```
<table>
<% @course.course_topics.each_with_index do |course_topic, i| %>
<td><%= course_topic.name %></td> 
<td><%= link_to "start session", topic_course_course_topic_path(:account_id =>current_user.account_id,:course_id=>@course,:id=>course_topic) %></td>

<td><%= link_to_function "Make Session End", :onclick => "return_ids('#{course_topic.id}')" %></td>


<div id="dialog-modal-<%= course_topic.id %>" class="session_end_form" title="Basic modal dialog">
    <%= form_tag(session_end_course_course_topic_path(current_user.account_id, "#{params[:id]}", course_topic.id), :method => :put) %>

    <%= hidden_field_tag :course_topic_id, course_topic.id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :user_account, "#{params[:account_id]}" %>

    <p><%= radio_button_tag :session_status, "session_break"%>Break Session</p>
    <p><%= radio_button_tag :session_status, "session_end" %>Session Finished</p>

    <div class="session_popup_buttons">
      <span style="margin-left: 10px;">
        <%= submit_tag "OK" %>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

</tr>
 <%end%>
</table>

<script>
  function return_ids(id) {
    $("#dialog-modal-" + id).dialog({
    height: 300,
     modal: true
  });
  }
</script>
```

May be i did wrong in passing ids, but i am not getting.

Comment: I solved it by changing form_tag to form_for as:                     <%= form_for :course, :url => session_end_course_course_topic_path(current_user.account_id, "#{params[:id]}", course_topic.id), :method => :put do %>

Answer (score 0):

Use `form_for` instead of `form_tag`

Comment: why form_tag didnot work, provide some suitable answer.